# Правильно ли поставлены знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

"Спасибо тем, кто меня любит, – вы делаете меня лучше." Или тире/вторая запятая лишние?

**Обновление**

А если полное предложение звучит так: "Есть прекрасная фраза: спасибо тем, кто меня любит (?) вы делаете меня лучше; спасибо тем, кто меня ненавидит (?) вы делаете меня сильнее." Тогда двоеточие уже не вставить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы поставил не тире и запятую, а двоеточие, так как вторая часть БСП объясняет причину того, о чем говорится в первой части.

**Обновление**

Это следовало бы оформить как прямую речь, и тогда двоеточия смотрелись бы вполне органично

Comment: Спасибо ))

Answer (score 1):

Знаки расставлены правильно. Запятые отделяют главное предложение от придаточного, тире как вывод.

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно. Это придаточное предложение. Запятая  здесь закрывает придаточное( изъяснительное), тире как вывод.